# Javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: java, android, smtp

I'm trying to send an email from my app using the Gmail smtp server. To do this, I'm using javax libraries.

MailSender.java

```
public class MailSender {

final String emailPort = "587";// gmail's smtp port for tls
final String smtpAuth = "true";
final String starttls = "true";
final String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";

String fromEmail;
String fromPassword;
String toEmail;
String emailSubject;
String emailBody;

Properties emailProperties;
Session mailSession;
MimeMessage emailMessage;

public MailSender() {

}

public MailSender(String fromEmail, String fromPassword, String toEmail, String emailSubject, String emailBody) {
    this.fromEmail = fromEmail;
    this.fromPassword = fromPassword;
    this.toEmail = toEmail;
    this.emailSubject = emailSubject;
    this.emailBody = emailBody;

    emailProperties = System.getProperties();
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", smtpAuth);
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", starttls);

    Log.i("MAIL_SENDER", "Mail server properties set.");
}

public MimeMessage createEmailMessage() throws AddressException, MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    mailSession = Session.getInstance(emailProperties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, fromPassword);
        }
    });
    emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

    emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, fromEmail));
    emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
    emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
    //emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");// for a html email
    emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email

    Log.i("MAIL_SENDER", "Email Message created.");

    return emailMessage;
}

public void sendMail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(emailHost, fromEmail, fromPassword);
    transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();

    Log.i("MAIL_SENDER", "Email sent successfully.");
}
```

}

This is how I send email from activity/service:

```
private void sendEmail(String email) throws Exception{
    String from = "myemail@gmail.com";
    String pass = "mypass";
    String to = email;
    String subject = getString(R.string.email_subject);
    String body = location_link;

    sendMailTask task = new sendMailTask();
    task.execute(from, pass, to, subject, body);
}

private class sendMailTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... args) {
        try {
            MailSender mail = new MailSender(args[0].toString(),
                    args[1].toString(), args[2].toString(), args[3].toString(),
                    args[4].toString());
            mail.createEmailMessage();
            mail.sendMail();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("EMAIL", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But each time it calls the conect() method, I get this error in LogCat:

```
04-17 12:18:05.996: E/EMAIL(4160): javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
04-17 12:18:05.996: E/EMAIL(4160):  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
04-17 12:18:05.996: E/EMAIL(4160):  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
04-17 12:18:05.996: E/EMAIL(4160):  at com.myapp.mail.MailSender.sendMail(MailSender.java:82)
04-17 12:18:05.996: E/EMAIL(4160):  at com.myapp.TrackingService$sendMailTask.doInBackground(TrackingService.java:380)
04-17 12:18:05.996: E/EMAIL(4160):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-17 12:18:05.996: E/EMAIL(4160):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-17 12:18:05.996: E/EMAIL(4160):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-17 12:18:05.996: E/EMAIL(4160):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-17 12:18:05.996: E/EMAIL(4160):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-17 12:18:05.996: E/EMAIL(4160):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

It has something to do with the autentification. In fact, I have received an email from google in my account telling that someone has tried to access my account...

Comment: @Josef I'm using the Authenticator. Does the one you have linked work diferent that the one from my code?

Comment: Try Host Name "smtp.googlemail.com" and SMTP Port "465",

Comment: @DhavalPatel changed to "smtp.googlemail.com" still with port "587" and same error appears. Changed booth things, smtp and port to "465", and now it does not throw exception, but neither it sends the message.

Answer (score 1):

Below Code is working fine for me. For that you need to download libarary from http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list link and commons-email from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/download_email.cgi link. Remove all other java mail library add these four library only;

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.Email;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;

private class MailClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Email email = new SimpleEmail();
                email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
                email.setSmtpPort(465);
                email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("abc@gmail.com", "abc_password"));
                email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
                email.setFrom("abc@gmail.com");
                email.setSubject("TestMail");
                email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
                email.addTo("dhavalpatel.244@gmail.com");
                email.send();
            } catch (EmailException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I usually have those 3 jar files. I'm trying with your code, but, where does the `Email` class came from? I don't get no import from the jar files...

Comment: So, you are using another kind of apache library or something? I cannot get those imports in a regular way

Comment: Are you using eclipse or android studio?

Comment: Eclipse, I've been having problems with jar files in AS

Comment: Sorry..forgot to tell you..Please Add jar from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/download_email.cgi link. Download commons-email-1.3.3-bin.zip. which contains commons-email-1.3.3.jar file.

Comment: I have double check this solution. Its working for me.. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Same autentification error: ` Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException` when calling javax.mail.Service.connect()

Comment: Have you set 2 step account verification for your google account?

Comment: Nope. I have that verified before

Comment: Double check your password or try with another gmail account.

Comment: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps Turn On  Access for less secure app. If you have it off.

Comment: Access for less secure app on. Error: `Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.googlemail.com Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException`

Comment: https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/AuthenticationFailedException.html say This exception is thrown when the connect method on a Store or Transport object fails due to an authentication failure (e.g., bad user name or password).

Comment: Triple check your username and password.

Comment: I'm on it, haven't had time till now to work with this. I'll try and I'll post the results